# Migrate Business Intelligence Development Studio 2005 .dtsx files to 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, ssis, visual-studio-2005

I have an old project using SSIS for data integration. I must use Visual studio 2005 with MySQL 2005. It doesn't seems to work if I mix 2010/2005. My question is can I migrate my .dtsx files to Visual studio 2010 ? I would like to not use many version of visual studio if possible.

After googling around about this dark technology I didn't found any revelant source of information. So any doc or pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is not currently possible please see this SSIS team blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2010/05/13/ssis-and-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: I was afraid this was the case. This is making me lose some hairs.

Comment: Fortunately, you can have VS 2005 (and 2008) and 2010 installed on the same machine and they work ok.  Just make sure you have a way of telling what version each project and package is, so you can keep them separate.  I added 2005 or 2008 (in my case) to the project name.